# Concatenated ssh command after exit

Tags: bash

To reproduce, open a terminal ssh session, now, execute the bash or sh shell, you will enter into another shell, the question is, exists any way to exit from the shell and execute in the first shell created in a concatenated command?

Example:

```
bash-4.1$ /bin/sh
sh-4.1$ exit;ls
exit
bash-4.1$
```

As you can see, "ls" command is not executed in the "bash" shell after "exit" command has been executed in "sh" shell.

Comment: Do you distinguish between `sh` and `ssh`? You began to speak about `ssh` and then run `/bin/sh`

Comment: Do the second command that should be run in **outer** shell use some output from the **inner** shell?

Comment: What does `ssh` have to do with this? Don't you see the same problem if you use a regular local shell?

Comment: If you post something after `exit`, it is lost. You need to change your workflow - the right workflow is to execute the command in the outer shell. See @DigitalRoss's answer for example.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve and why is the solution posted by @DigitalRoss not correct?

Comment: Using a heredoc to pass input to the SSH session or inner shell is more likely to be appropriate here, but that's with a fair bit of guessing at the OP's actual intent.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...

```
$ $(ssh othersystem echo ls)
```

Fundamentally, you need a reverse communication channel. An interactive target shell is a particularly unsuitable transmitter.

One channel you *do* have is the exit status, so:

```
$ ssh othersystem
other$ exit 5
$ if [ $? -eq 5 ]; then echo how now; ls; fi # whatever
```

Comment: the problem appears in the local machine so using ssh hostname is not working

Comment: The idea is exit from the actual shell and execute command in the first shell created.

Initally i have executed exit;ls as you can see in above but is not working.

Comment: Actually I *did* exit from the remote shell and then the command echoed on the remote shell *did* execute in the local source shell.  Anyway, I added a second idea for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it in what you are calling a "concatenated command." The issue is that the `exit;ls` is a command given to the "sh" shell to execute. You are typing it in the "sh" command prompt after all, and once the "sh" exits, the command you gave it doesn't exist anymore.

As for the "bash" shell, well, it is busy running the "sh" shell until it exits; only then can "bash" run a different command. As far as the "bash" shell is concern, it is just running "a command," and when the command exits, it will have its return code and that's it. They don't communicate between them.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you want to use this for? If you always want to run `ls` after `sh`, you could run it like this: `# /bin/sh; ls`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `ls` command to be executed by the original shell, you need to put it in the command line for that shell:

```
bash-4.1$ /bin/sh; ls
sh-4.1$ exit
<output of ls>
bash-4.1$
```

When you type `exit;ls` to the `sh` process, it reads the entire line and executes the commands there; the `ls` command is not left in the standard input stream to be read by the `bash` process.

Answer (score 0):

Though there is [no direct possibility to return data](https://serverfault.com/q/37796/268923) from child chell to parent shell, there are

---

1) **Quick and dirty**

Place the commands for the internal shell into a script (`1.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
a=5; b=7;
echo "export "a="$a"
echo "export "b="$b"
```

Then, in the external shell call the inner script (shell) this way:

```
`./1.sh`
```

Check the results again in the external shell:

```
:~$ echo $a
5
:~$ echo $b
7
```

---

2) write all your data to the temp file. You can use **tmpfs** (`mount | grep tmpfs` to determine where it is miunted) tha is a block device in RAM not to save anything to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a process on a remote host which generates a script of commands to be executed back on the local host then you can pipe the output from the remote host to a new shell session:

```
ssh remotehost "echo ls" | sh
```

If you need it to be run in the invoking shell itself then this can work:

```
eval $(ssh remotehost "echo ls")
```

Obviously you must trust the remote host to not generate hostile output such as `rm -rf $HOME/*` or `rm -rf /`.